# Can anyone point me to (or post) an array of every HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, tags

Can anyone point me to a way to generate an array (or a pre-generated array) of every HTML tag as a string?  I need this because I have a library which expects me to whitelist every tag I want (and I want all of them).  I tried to Google for this, but was (surprisingly) unable to find it.

In other words, the array would look something like:

```
const htmlTags = ['a', 'base', 'br', ...]
```

Comment: var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

Comment: If you just want to format it in Javascript array syntax, you could easily use a macro in your preferred code editor.

Comment: @Alex Shiman Great idea ... except it only works if the page I'm on has every type of tag on it.

Comment: @epascarello and nullability I know there are many lists of HTML tags on the web, but they all require macros/find-replace/regular expressions (ie. work) to get them in to an arrray format.  I was hoping one might already exist somewhere so that (being a lazy programmer) I can avoid that work (and also avoid accidentally taking out half the list with a bad regex I don't realize is bad or something like that).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I went to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element), copied the tags from the screen. I replaced < with ", I replace > with ", and manually deleted the headings

```
["a",
"abbr",
"acronym",
"address",
"applet",
"area",
"article",
"aside",
"audio",
"b",
"base",
"basefont",
"bdi",
"bdo",
"bgsound",
"big",
"blink",
"blockquote",
"body",
"br",
"button",
"canvas",
"caption",
"center",
"cite",
"code",
"col",
"colgroup",
"content",
"data",
"datalist",
"dd",
"decorator",
"del",
"details",
"dfn",
"dir",
"div",
"dl",
"dt",
"element",
"em",
"embed",
"fieldset",
"figcaption",
"figure",
"font",
"footer",
"form",
"frame",
"frameset",
"h1",
"h2",
"h3",
"h4",
"h5",
"h6",
"head",
"header",
"hgroup",
"hr",
"html",
"i",
"iframe",
"img",
"input",
"ins",
"isindex",
"kbd",
"keygen",
"label",
"legend",
"li",
"link",
"listing",
"main",
"map",
"mark",
"marquee",
"menu",
"menuitem",
"meta",
"meter",
"nav",
"nobr",
"noframes",
"noscript",
"object",
"ol",
"optgroup",
"option",
"output",
"p",
"param",
"plaintext",
"pre",
"progress",
"q",
"rp",
"rt",
"ruby",
"s",
"samp",
"script",
"section",
"select",
"shadow",
"small",
"source",
"spacer",
"span",
"strike",
"strong",
"style",
"sub",
"summary",
"sup",
"table",
"tbody",
"td",
"template",
"textarea",
"tfoot",
"th",
"thead",
"time",
"title",
"tr",
"track",
"tt",
"u",
"ul",
"var",
"video",
"wbr",
"xmp"]
```

Comment: Due to contents changed, I create [PHP code for this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a83fc026f8b9c5620fde14fb182d157ae349a16d). Please feel free to use it.

Comment: Depending on what your using this for, you may want to add "!DOCTYPE" and "!--" to the list

Answer (score 1):

Use the specification i.e. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1

Has a table. Cut'n'paste it

**EDIT**

Just highlight the table. Cut'n'pasterto notepad++.Regex delete after first space - got

```
a
abbr
address
area
article
aside
audio
b
base
bdi
bdo
blockquote
body
br
button
canvas
caption
cite
code
col
colgroup
data
datalist
dd
del
details
dfn
dialog
div
dl
dt
em
embed
fieldset
figcaption
figure
footer
form
h1,
head
header
hr
html
i
iframe
img
input
ins
kbd
keygen
label
legend
li
link
main
map
mark
meta
meter
nav
noscript
object
ol
optgroup
option
output
p
param
pre
progress
q
rp
rt
ruby
s
samp
script
section
select
small
source
span
strong
style
sub
summary
sup
table
tbody
td
textarea
tfoot
th
thead
time
title
tr
track
u
ul
var
video
wbr
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However unfortunately it's really more like "Copy/paste the entire table, concoct some sort of regex to remove all the other columns, run that regex, fix any issues with the regex, try again ..." so if one exists I'd hope to just be able to use a list that's already in array format.

Comment: Thank you for the edited answer; I upvoted it, but @epascarello beat you to the punch (just barely) on the acceptance.